# can JBpm use Spring beans instead of classes?

Tags: spring, jbpm

We exploring migration of old J2EE project which has workflows kind of scenarios to be re-written with JBpm. I have referred few examples which mostly uses the Java class's for activity or task. Spring integration with JBPM is more of initialization of JBPM. Is it technically feasible to inject bean in substitution of java pojo classes?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use spring bean in JBPM using domainSpecific work item handlers. Custom tasks can be defined with some required parameters such as bean name, method name, invocation parameters etc. These custom work item handler will implement ContextAware interface of Spring and get access to container. 
This work in similar lines ServiceTask for JBPM which uses JAVA pojo classes.

```
<bean id="workflowLauncherProcessor" class="workflow.WorkflowLauncherProcessor">
        <property name="manager" ref="runtimeManager"></property>
        <property name="workItemHandlerMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="SpringAsyncTask" value-ref="asyncWorkItemHandler"></entry>
                <entry key="SpringSyncTask" value-ref="syncWorkItemHandler"></entry>
                <entry key="SpringDirectTask" value-ref="directWorkItemHandler"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="directWorkItemHandler" class="workflow.handler.SpringDirectBeanInvokeWorkItemHandler">
    </bean>
```

Implementation class will look as below

```
package workflow.handler;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.jbpm.bpmn2.handler.WorkItemHandlerRuntimeException;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItem;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItemHandler;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItemManager;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

import com.scb.cashport.common.util.CommonConstants;

/**
 * The Class SpringDirectBeanInvokeWorkItemHandler.
 *
 */
public class SpringDirectBeanInvokeWorkItemHandler implements WorkItemHandler, ApplicationContextAware {

    /** The Constant LOGGER. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SpringDirectBeanInvokeWorkItemHandler.class);

    /** The application context. */
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItemHandler#executeWorkItem(org.kie.api
     * .runtime.process.WorkItem, org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItemManager)
     */
    @Override
    public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
        Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            String bean = (String) workItem.getParameter(CommonConstants.BEAN);
            Object inputParam = (Object) workItem.getParameter(CommonConstants.INPUT_PARAM);
            boolean cascasdeInput = Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(workItem.getParameter(CommonConstants.CASCADE_INPUT)));
            String operation = (String) workItem.getParameter(CommonConstants.OPERATION);
            String parameterDefinition = (String) workItem.getParameter(CommonConstants.PARAMETER_TYPE);
            String parameter = (String) workItem.getParameter(CommonConstants.PARAMETER);
            LOGGER.info("Spring Direct Bean Work Item begin for bean: {} and input: {}", bean, inputParam);
            Object outParam = null;
            Object instance = applicationContext.getBean(bean);
            if (instance != null) {
                try {
                    Class<?>[] classes = null;
                    Object[] params = null;
                    if (parameterDefinition != null) {
                        if (parameterDefinition.contains(CommonConstants.COMMA)) {
                            String[] parameterDefinitionArray = parameterDefinition.split(CommonConstants.COMMA);
                            String[] parameternArray = parameter.split(CommonConstants.COMMA);
                            if (parameterDefinitionArray.length != parameternArray.length) {
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Paramter types and parameters are not matching");
                            }
                            classes = new Class<?>[parameterDefinitionArray.length];
                            params = new Object[parameterDefinitionArray.length];
                            for (int i = 0; i < parameterDefinitionArray.length; i++) {
                                classes[i] = Class.forName(parameterDefinitionArray[i]);
                                String paramKey = parameternArray[i];
                                if (paramKey.startsWith("'")) {
                                    params[i] = paramKey.substring(1, (paramKey.length() - 1));
                                } else {
                                    params[i] = BeanUtils.getProperty(inputParam, parameternArray[i]);
                                }

                            }
                        } else {
                            classes = new Class<?>[]{Class.forName(parameterDefinition)};
                            params = new Object[]{BeanUtils.getProperty(inputParam, parameter)};
                        }
                    }
                    Method method = instance.getClass().getMethod(operation, classes);
                    outParam = method.invoke(instance, params);
                    if (cascasdeInput) {
                        String resultParameter = (String) workItem.getParameter(CommonConstants.RESULT_PARAMETER);
                        BeanUtils.setProperty(inputParam, resultParameter, outParam);
                        results.put(CommonConstants.INPUT_PARAM, inputParam);
                        results.put(CommonConstants.OUT_PARAM, inputParam);
                    } else {
                        results.put(CommonConstants.OUT_PARAM, outParam);
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException cnfe) {
                    handleException(cnfe, instance.getClass().getName(), operation, parameterDefinition);
                }
            } else {
                throw new InstanceNotFoundException(bean + " bean instance not found");
            }
            LOGGER.info("Spring Direct Bean Work Item completed for bean: {} and input: {}", bean, inputParam);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
            throw new WorkItemHandlerRuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), results);
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItemHandler#abortWorkItem(org.kie.api
     * .runtime.process.WorkItem, org.kie.api.runtime.process.WorkItemManager)
     */
    @Override
    public void abortWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware#setApplicationContext
     * (org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)
     */
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

Workflow launcher will be as below

```
RuntimeEngine engine = manager.getRuntimeEngine(EmptyContext.get());
KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();
for (Entry<String, WorkItemHandler> entry : workItemHandlerMap.entrySet()) {
    ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
...
ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess(processId, parameter);
Object variable = ((WorkflowProcessInstance) processInstance).getVariable("resultr");
```